# Best way to lock down Android tablet?

Tags: security, multi-user

We're deploying a number of Android tablets into the field next year. Ideally, we'd like them locked down somewhat so that the users can only access certain apps and settings. Configuring a restricted user seems to work, but in the event the device is shut off or rebooted, with newer versions of Android (and the accompanying default encryption of the internal storage), a full user has to be the first to sign in before a restricted user can access the device.

What is currently the best way to work around this? My first preference would be something directly supported by the OS, but I also see a number of "kiosk" apps out there.

I'm currently working with a Samsung Galaxy Tab A7, if that matters.

Comment: Some kiosk like apps make use of the Device Administration API which works similar to an MDM solution just on-device. Unfortunately the API is deprecated since Android 9 which means it is now still available but may be removed or slimmed down regarding its features in future versions.

Comment: Thanks, @Robert  I'd considered MDMs, but it seems the offerings are more mature for iOS than they are for Android, though I am totally open to suggestions.